# Slider nav not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I can not seem to get my navigation bar to toggle. I want the navigation bar to toggle left. Fairly new  obviously but I don't believe my ON CLICK function is the issue here. I tried looking into the css to see if that's where the issue was but couldn't find any. Could the issue be just how I structured my JavaScript?

```js
(function() {
    var bodyEl = $('body'),
        navToggleBtn = bodyEl.find('.nav-toggle-btn')
    
    navToggleBtn.on('click', function(e){
        bodyEl.toggleClass('.active-nav')
        e.preventDefault()
    })
})();
```

```css
 header{
  display: flex;
 }

 nav {
  display: block;
 }

 nav ul{
  display: block;
 }

 nav {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 8em;
  background: blue;
  right: 0;
  transform: translate3d(8em, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(8em, 0, 0);
  transition: transform 0.4s ease;
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.4s ease;
 }

 .active-nav nav {
  transform: translate(-8em, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-8em, 0, 0);
 }

 nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 100px;
 }

 nav ul li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
 }

 .nav-toggle-btn{
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  float: right;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
  top: 0;
  left: -2.85em;
 }

 section {
  transition: transform 0.4s ease;
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.4s ease;
 }

 .active-nav section {
  transform: translate3d(-8em, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-8em, 0, 0);
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
    <a href="index.html"><img alt="" height="65" src="#"
    width="89"></a>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <a href="#" class="nav-toggle-btn"></a>

        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="resume.html">Resume</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
   </header>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/kaa778n0/

The dot in the class inside the function is not needed. It is a className not a selector.

```
bodyEl.toggleClass('active-nav')
```

You apply the style to the section not the nav.

```
.active-nav nav {
    transform: translate3d(-8em, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-8em, 0, 0);
}
```